# Cannot find name 'undefined' in union type

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'm declaring a variable:

```
Id: string | string[] | undefined;
```

This results in error

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'undefined'.

According to [Basic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) `undefined` is a valid type in TypeScript.

[Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) mentions union types like `number | undefined`.

What's wrong with my union type declaration?

Comment: What Typescript version are you using?

Comment: This works fine in the playground. I assume you mean you are declaring a property, right?

Comment: I'm using TypeScript 1.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `undefined` type, together with the `null` type, was only introduced in [TypeScript 2.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#null--and-undefined-aware-types). **You're probably using an older version of TypeScript.**

Comment: That's true, thanks for pointing it out. It's a pity that accessing the official wiki documents for older versions requires browsing git history.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Id: string | string[] | 'undefined';
```

Also you can use `any` datatype.

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP wants. And using `any` defeats the entire purpose.

Comment: any defeats the entire purpose thats true
But 'undefined' didnt give me error

Comment: My bad type, its not `undefined` its 'undefined'

Comment: `'undefined'` will not give you an error, but it also means something entirely different.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, the `'undefined'` type is a **string literal type** describing the exact string `'undefined'`, **not** the `undefined` (`void 0`) value.